# Refering to colors using numbers

Tags: macros, color, xstring

I want to create a command allowing me to colour arbitrary text with a color designed by a number (e.g. 1 = Green, 2 = Blue, etc).
To that purpose, I create a first command, giving the name of the color depending on the number (and this command works fine).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\levelcolor}[1]{\IfEqCase{#1}{{1}{ForestGreen}{2}{CornflowerBlue}{3}{BurntOrange}{4}{Red}{5}{Black}{6}{Mulberry}}}
\newcommand{\level}[2]{\colorbox{\levelcolor{#2}}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\level{Test}{4}
\end{document}
```

When using the result of this command inside another command, I get an error message:

```
! Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.11 \level{Test}{4}
```

Any idea of what I could do to fix that (and why the above code cannot work)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Isn't it simpler to say `\colorlet{level1}{ForestGreen}` and define `\newcommand{\levelcolor}[1]{levelcolor#1}`?

Comment: I did not know I could do that. It does exactly what I expected ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color specification in the argument to `\colorbox` should fully expand to a color name; since `\IfEqCase` does much work with its arguments and this work includes doing assignments, it can't be used in places where full expansion is needed.

A better (and simpler) strategy is to say

```
\colorlet{levelcolor1}{ForestGreen}
\colorlet{levelcolor2}{CornflowerBlue}
\colorlet{levelcolor3}{BurntOrange}
\colorlet{levelcolor4}{Red}
\colorlet{levelcolor5}{Black}
\colorlet{levelcolor6}{Mulberry}

\newcommand{\levelcolor}[1]{levelcolor#1}
```

So `\colorbox{\levelcolor{1}}{text}` will become

```
\colorbox{levelcolor1}{text}
```

and the `\colorlet` chosen color will be used.

---

A different possibility, that can turn up handy in some other cases, is provided by `expl3`:

```
\usepackage{xparse} % loads also expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\levelcolor}{m}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{ForestGreen}
    {2}{CornflowerBlue}
    {3}{BurntOrange}
    {4}{Red}
    {5}{Black}
    {6}{Mulberry}
   }
   {Cyan} % overflow
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

With this you may even do `\levelcolor{1+1}` (not that it's so useful), but also pass a counter's value as `\value{counter}`.